# Plugin with id 'ly.img.android.sdk' not Found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, photoeditorsdk

I am using  "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0"  along with "@capacitor/android": "3.4.0".

Installed Cordova-plugin-photoeditorsdk via npm and imported in a component but we try to compile we are getting an error as "Plugin with id 'ly.img.android.sdk' not Found" in android studio.

[image]

Comment: Did you run `npx cap sync`?

Comment: yes, i ran npx cap sync after installing this package